# Login & Register Popup functionality in Magento

Tags: php, ajax, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

I want Login and Register functionality in Ajax popup box after loading the page. Can anyone give me any suggestions for that how to achieve that?

I am using Magento 1.7.

Comment: This works perfect https://magecomp.com/magento-mobile-login.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use Youma Ajax Module.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/youama-ajax-login-and-register.html

I've used this in many projects and there was no issue.

Hope this may helpful for your project . . ..  :)

Comment: thank for your reply but i need to develop when the homepage is loading in the browser for first time i want to display register popup like newsletter popup while first time loading......did u get my point????

Answer (score 0):

it can be more simple :

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
$session->login($username, $password);
```

put it in a try block for catching login errors :)